Is there any matlab built-in function or libraries to calculate $\frac{d(\ln A)}{dA}$?
we can first conduct spectral decomposition of an positive definite isotropic tensor $A$ and then we can define $\ln(A)$, then we can define the frechet derivative of it, but how to calculate this in matlab quickly?

I think you may find some assistance in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231635.

See logm_frechet_pade in the Matrix Function Toolbox. There is a related paper with descriptions of more recent algorithms;
The software is on Matlab Central, which was easy to find once I discovered the latest version of Catalogue of Software for Matrix Functions by Nick Higham and Edvin Hopkins. The announcement of catalogue version 3 (2020), a link to the eprint, and request for updates is on Higham's website.

it seems that this library conduct derivative wrt a vector, but I want to calculate d(ln(A))/d(A), here A is a matrix

@YuerWu It computes the action of the Fréchet derivative on a vector.

$
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\L{\left}
\def\R{\right}
\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\m#1{ \L[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\R] }
\def\mc#1{ \L[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\R] }
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\L(#1\R)}
$A recent paper by Jan Magnus contains an interesting formula for the vectorized gradient (aka Jacobian) of the matrix function $\,F=e^A$.
But his formula actually holds for any analytic function $F=f(A)$, and it is easy to show (after reading his paper) that
$$\eqalign{
&{\large\Phi} = f\L(\mc{A^T\otimes I& I\otimes I \\\hline 0&I\otimes A}\R) = \mc{
F^T\otimes I & \p{\vc{F}}{\vc{A}} \\\hline 0 & I\otimes F } \\
&\p{\vc F}{\vc A} = \Big(e_1\otimes I\Big)^T{\large\Phi}\:\Big(e_2\otimes I\Big) \\
}$$
This provides a semi-closed form solution at the cost of evaluating the function for a large triangular matrix argument.
Reshaping the $(n^2\times n^2)$ Jacobian matrix recovers the full 4th-order
$(n\times n\times n\times n)$ tensor gradient.

Let $f$ be any sufficiently regular function (including the logarithm); then, one can prove that
$$
f\left(\begin{bmatrix} A & H\\ 0 & A\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} f(A) & M\\ 0 & f(A)\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $M$ is the directional derivative in the direction $H$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(A+tH).
$$
For a proof, see e.g. Higham's book Functions of matrices.
The matrix $L = \frac{d(\ln A)}{dA}$ is $n^2\times n^2$; after de-vectorizing, you can see it as an operator from the matrix space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to itself; so the previous trick allows you to compute $\operatorname{vec} M = L \operatorname{vec} H$ for any given $H\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
In particular, by applying the trick with $H = E_{i,j}$ (the matrix with $1$ in position $(i,j)$ and zero elsewhere), you can compute one column of $L$. You can repeat this $n^2$ times, to compute all columns of $L$.
With this method, you can compute the full matrix $L$ in $O(n^5)$. This should be cheaper than the method suggested in greg's answer. But, depending on your application, just being able to compute $L\operatorname{vec} H$ for any given $H$ may be enough.
The Matlab function logm_frechet_pade suggested in another answer contains a slightly cheaper function to compute $M$ from $H$.
